# Create SVG elements from collection without explicitly setting coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm new to SVG, so I don't know if I'm missing something obvious and simple.

In every lesson on creating SVG elements, `x` and `y` coordinates must be explicitly set for element to be drawn. But is there a way for a browser to draw one svg shape right next to another, without explicitly specifying coordinates, like DOM does when you write `<div>content1</div><div>content2</div>`?

What I want is:

Having a collection of data for elements (let's say, they are all rectangles with only `width` and `height` specified), is there a way to draw all of them sequentially in a row (horizontally)? I don't want to manually set coordinates for each element, just call `foreach` element in array and expect browser to figure out coordinates from each element's `width` property.

Is this achievable only with some script that dynamically calculates bounding box for each element or there is some simpler way?

Comment: No, all SVG is absolutely positioned. You'd need to write a script.

Comment: Why don't you create distinct SVG elements?